# Apply readEntity to all exceptions and replace null cause with correct exception from ByteArrayInputStream

Tags: java, spring, exception, jersey

The code base I am working with is spring and jersey.

I am on this new code base, and within the 500 exceptions got back from REST call in response.context.entityContent, I found that the RO containing the true exception is a ByteArrayInputStream.

Right now I can extract the server exception message with ex.getResponse().readEntity(CustomRO.class).getMessage().

The 500 exceptions containing the RO, however, does not contain the cause (ex.getCause() = null).
Is there a way I can apply read Entity to all exceptions on the client side, get the exception in the RO and put it as the cause of the 500 InternalServerErrorException?

Please correct me if I am wrong in any of my thoughts, and let me know if there is any standard that I should follow. 
Also it is my first time asking here, so I am sorry if my wording is long or not to the point